# Running Spring Boot test inside Docker container

Tags: docker, spring-boot-test

I am wondering if it is possible to run Spring Boot test inside a Docker container. I would like to test my service in the environment as close to the real one as possible. I am already using  Testcontainers and Localstack to setup my environment (Postgres, AWS secrets manager etc.), but couldn't find any way to run my service inside Docker. Ideally I would like to test my service inside Localstack's EC2 instance, but just testing it as Docker container would be sufficient. I have Dockerfile at the root of my project and am using Gradle Palantir plugin to build the container. The bootstrap section of my test:

```
@Testcontainers
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test","jpa"})
@SpringBootTest(classes = PayoutsApplication.class, webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
                properties = {"aws.paramstore.enabled=false", "aws.secretsmanager.enabled=false"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextInstanceDataAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextRegionProviderAutoConfiguration.class
})
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = PayoutsApplicationTests.CustomLoader.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, PayoutsApplicationTests.class})
class MyApplicationTests extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {
    
    private static AWSSecretsManager awsSecretsManager;
    private static AWSSimpleSystemsManagement ssmClient;
    
    // we need it to execute the listeners
    public static class CustomLoader extends SpringBootContextLoader {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplication getSpringApplication() {
            PropertiesListener listener = new PropertiesListener();
            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(listener, "awsSecretsManager", awsSecretsManager);
            ReflectionTestUtils.setField(listener, "ssmClient", ssmClient);
            SpringApplication app = super.getSpringApplication();
            app.addListeners(listener);
            return app;
        }
    }
    
    static DockerImageName localstackImage = DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:0.11.3");
    
    
    private static final LocalStackContainer.Service[] TEST_SERVICES = {
            LocalStackContainer.Service.SECRETSMANAGER,
            LocalStackContainer.Service.SSM,
            LocalStackContainer.Service.EC2,
    };
    
    static LocalStackContainer awsLocalStackContainers = new LocalStackContainer(localstackImage)
            .withServices(TEST_SERVICES).withEnv("LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME", "localhost")
            .withEnv("HOSTNAME", "localhost");
   
    
    @Container
    public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQL =
      new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:13.1")
            .withUsername("clusteradmin")
            .withPassword("testPassword")
            .withDatabaseName("public");

  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void postgresqlProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {  
    registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQL::getJdbcUrl);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQL::getPassword);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQL::getUsername);
  }

 ...
```